# oauth2 OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService().getCurrentUser() crashes

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid

Context:

I have an angularJs app with a jersey bachend server running on app engine. Until now I used (the much simpler) openId APi to authenticate my users but now it seems this is going to be removed and oAuth2 is the "new" thing.

Question:

I have the following code to using apacha oltu to authenticate my user:

```
  @GET
  public Response step1()
      throws ServletException, IOException, URISyntaxException, OAuthSystemException {

    OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
    .authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.GOOGLE)
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
             .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
    .setRedirectURI(REDIRECT_URI)
    .setResponseType("code")
    .buildQueryMessage();

    logger.info("start oauth process: " + request.getLocationUri());

    //We send a redirect request to the browser so it can go to the consent screen of google.
    return Response.status(Response.Status.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT).location(new URI(request.getLocationUri())).build();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("loggedin")
  public Response getCode(@QueryParam("code") String code)
      throws ServletException, IOException, URISyntaxException, OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException, OAuthRequestException {

    logger.info("response from redirect. We obtained the following code: " + code);

    OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
    .tokenProvider(OAuthProviderType.GOOGLE)
    .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setCode(code)
             .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
    .setRedirectURI(REDIRECT_URI)
    .buildBodyMessage();

    OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
    OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse tokenResponse = client.accessToken(request, OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class);

    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "token: " + tokenResponse.getAccessToken() + " valid to: " + tokenResponse.getExpiresIn());

    return Response.status(Response.Status.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT).location(new URI("../index.html")).build();
  }
```

The problem now is that `OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService().getCurrentUser()` crashes with InvalidOAuthParametersException.

I found a similar question here on stackoverflow but the solution is not applicable/didn't work for me. The oauth process itself seems to be in order: I get an access token and a correct valid period. (I assume if something went wrong during the process I would get a empty/null token from the oltu and not a string which looks like a token string).

Previously I used the UserService to access the underlying user object. But it seems that this only works with openId.

An alternative to my oltu approach would be to use google+ sign in stuff.
The reason I don't went for this is I only found one example and this used some javascript stuff - I want to handle all oauth stuff strictly on the server and not include any other js library.

Is their an alternative to access some sort of user object for "id" and "is the user logged in"? (In UserService.getCurrentUser() null is returned if the user is not logged in).

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

> Is their an alternative to access some sort of user object for "id" and "is the user logged in"? (In UserService.getCurrentUser() null is returned if the user is not logged in).

The valid *stack overflow* answer:

> Yes.

Please review the guidelines for questions so that you can get an answerable question in future. This question is too broad and may attract opinionated answers.

Now, I don't want to just be snarky and tell you SO isn't the place for this discussion, since it's a valid question (albeit an involved one). You should post questions like this to [the google group for appengine](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine).